# Creating a view to show a user the flag he/she has been flagged with

Tags: 7, views, users, flags

I have created 3 flags for users and only admin can flag it. Lets say the name of the flag is "Cool", "Boring", "Super". The admin goes to the profile of user A and flags him with "Cool" and "Super" flag. Now when 'A' logs in, he/she should see a view something like this:

```
Flags:
Super
Cool
```

How can i achieve this view.